# Different rendering in SWT Browser with setText and setUrl

Tags: css, eclipse, swt

I'm trying to write an Eclipse plugin that displays some information as an HTML page. For this I want to use SWT `Browser` widget. The problem is that when I set browser's content via `setText`, `nth-child` selectors do not work, but when I set the exact same content via `setUrl("file://...`, they work correctly. Why the rendering is different and how can I achieve the same rendering with `setText` as with `setUrl`?

I'm creating the `Browser` with `SWT.NONE`, since I do not want to force users to install Safari or Firefox.

This is the HTML where the problem is reproducible:

```
<!doctype html><html><head>
<style type="text/css">
    div:nth-child(2n) { background-color: #f00; }
</style>
</head><body>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: What is the HTML that you put in via setText? 
Did you escape it correctly? Do image references work?

Comment: Added the HTML. It contains no image references.

Comment: I don't have an InternetExplorer here, does this snippet work in the IE that you have installed? Is that the HTML you pass into setText, or is it the source you get, when you right-click on the Browser and select "display source".

Comment: It displays correcty in IE and the source (when I get it from `Browser`) is exactly this HTML.

Comment: When you get it via `getText()`, I presume? If so, try rightclicking and use the IE show-source. It's still possible that there's a problem with the escaping. Java strings are Unicode, maybe you have unicode-escape sequences in there.

Comment: No, I've checked source through right-clicking on the actual view, like you're suggesting. Also, no Unicode (or escapes) there.

Comment: Hm, and the source is exactly the same like when set via file://? If you start the Browser with SWT.MOZILLA or WEBKIT, does it work?

Comment: Yes, the source is identical. Regarding `SWT.WEBKIT` — it doesn't work (even though I've installed Safari). Neither does `SWT.MOZILLA`: both crash at start.

Comment: And I am actually ok with using the default (IE's) engine on Windows: it renders nth-child fine.

Comment: The crashing at start can happen when you use 64bit JVM / 64bit SWT. Other than that, i'm out of ideas, sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having used the browser's `setText()` method extensively, I've not seen any behavior like what you're describing.

Is it possible that this is a local intranet quirks-mode / compatibility mode issue?  IE defaults its rendering engine differently based on the source of the content - and, by default, it behaves differently when rendering intranet content versus internet content (and content on your local filesystem is treated as intranet content.)  That's my recollection anyway, all I remember for sure is that there's a fair amount of voodoo unless you explicitly set the compatibility header.

Does adding the following meta tag change the behavior?

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

Also, do you have an appropriate `DOCTYPE` defined in the HTML you're adding with `setText()`?

Comment: Didn't know that about IE. The header solved the problem; thank you!